# What should I do if I am unsure of the category of a question I'm asking?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question that I'd like to ask on the stackexchange community, but I'm not sure which site to ask it on.

The question is something like

```
Are there any physical stores (not online) for makers and DIYers near Vancouver, BC?
```

Which site should I ask it on? The only site that is related to DIY is home improvement, but I am also trying to find electronics and microcontrollers. If there isn't a site, should we make a new one just for makers? Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Couldn't you just check Yellow Pages online?

Answer (score 10):

> Which site should I ask it on?

None of them.

This is a request for a list, which will degrade in quality over time. Entries will get stale, and votes will only reflect the popularity of a store.

It is the kind of question that is entirely unsuitable for our sites.

Comment: Should I use something like _YAHOO ANSWERS??_ then?

Comment: @Pyraminx - sure. They will take anything ;)

Comment: something else: There was a request for a list on ell, and I answered it. It has been on for months already without degrading.

Comment: @Pyraminx - some sites have different rules. I don't know what the question you asked was, and the English languages, as far as I know, doesn't move as fast as software and hardware do, so answers are less likely to degrade. That doesn't mean list questions are OK elsewhere on the network.